# How come we can create an object of an Interface when implementing Room Database?

Tags: android, object, kotlin, interface, dao

Can somebody please explain this to me! We all know we can **not** create an object of an interface in Java and Kotlin. We can only implement an interface from a class . So how come, when it comes to **Room Database** we are being able to create an object of **DAO** which is in fact an Interface inside a Repository class.

**Following is the Dao Interface :**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface WordDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedWords(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Word>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(word: Word)

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

**Following is the Repository class where Dao is being used as an object:**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData

class WordRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao) {

    val allWords: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Word>> = wordDao.getAlphabetizedWords()

    suspend fun insert(word: Word) {
        wordDao.insert(word)
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not create one . Dao dependency will be provided by the `Room Database` . Follow [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you do not create WordDao, Room generates a class that implements WordDao and room creates code for this class. So when you get WordDao you get a class room generated that implements WordDao.